# LDAPS 636 Works on Domain Controllers except Azure Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ad-certificate-services

I have a Domain Controller (Server 2016) in Azure. The Azure network this system is on is connected via a Virtual network gateway (VPN) to the on-prem network and the network engineers have configured this network to be trusted and thus is inside the firewall. We have a PKI infrastructure with a Root and Subordinate CA on the on-prem network and LDAPS works with any domain controller on-prem.

Regarding the Azure system: It's joined to the domain and event viewer and all that looks good. It is in its own AD Site in Sites and Services. Everything looks good, I can ping the machine from my on-prem network and all LDAP related ports are opened via Port queries. We see no errors in the Event Log either.

On a Windows 10 machine on the non-Azure network (in the Default-First-Site), I can LDAP 636 to any domain controller on-premises in that site but cannot I cannot LDAP 636 to this Azure domain controller. I am using `LDP.exe` and receive the error:

`ld = ldap_open("azure.fqdn.com", 636);
Error <0x51>: Fail to connect to azure.fqdn.com.`

I can LDAP 389 to this machine. I can telnet 636 to this machine. So it seems like something is up with the certificates. I just am not sure what.

In the certificate store is a certificate with the SAN of the FQDN for this machine with enhanced key usage of

`Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2), Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)`

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try Zenmap ssl-cert script against the server and see what it comes back with for the certificate.  https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-cert.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need check if the certificate is bind properly to the service.

I suggest downloading testsslserver from here http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/ (according to the .net version installed on your machine).

Then try running: "TestSSLServer.exe AzureADFQDN 636" and see the output.

One known issue is that there is another certificate in the ADSC service personal store without a private key. The service binds to that certificate and fails. Deleting it will solve the problem. 
You can read more about it here https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1420908-ldaps-not-connecting